# DateDifference inconsistency - feature or bug?

Tags: date-and-time

The following code attempts to measure the difference in months between the last day of a year and the first day of a month in the following year.

`QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, #, 1}, "Month"] & /@ Range@12`

which produces

```
{0.0322581, 1.03571, 2.03571, 3.03333, 4.03333, .03333,
6.03333, 7.03226, 8.03333, 9.03333, 10.0333, 11.0333}
```

However, the results are not what I would expect. Specifically, I would expect the denominator in calculating the fractional part to be the number of days in that particular month, i.e.

```
1/{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31} // N

{0.0322581, 0.0357143, 0.0322581, 0.0333333, 0.0322581, 0.0333333, 0.0322581, 0.0322581, 0.0333333, 0.0322581, 0.0333333, 0.0322581}
```

What appears to be used instead is a sequence of days in each month of the year which is;

31, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30

which doesn't make much sense. Not only that, but it leads to nonsensical results such as the following;

```
In[359]:= DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, 3, 28}, "Month"]

Out[359]= Quantity[3, "Months"]

In[360]:= DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, 3, 29}, "Month"]

Out[360]= Quantity[3.03571, "Months"]

In[361]:= DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, 3, 30}, "Month"]

Out[361]= Quantity[3.07143, "Months"]

In[362]:= DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, 3, 31}, "Month"]

Out[362]= Quantity[3, "Months"]
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? I can't see how this would be a feature.

Many thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: This seems perfectly reasonable. `UnitConvert[Quantity[1.0, "Months"], "Days"]` is not an integer multiple of days so this is expected.

Comment: I disagree. Your example above takes a month in isolation. The result is 30.4167 which is the average length of a month in a year (multiply by 12 to get 365).
However, DateDifference in taking the difference between two specific dates - there is a context provided. Also, if you reread my post, you'll see that the denominator that is being used for the number of days in a month is not constant but does not appear to fit a pattern that makes sense (at least to me).

Comment: You're asking for the date difference in units of months which is units of 30.4167 days. It's documented behaviour, not a bug. The unit cannot change depending on which month it's in. Use mixed radix units `{"Month", "Day"}` instead.

Comment: It sounds like some application of `DateRange` is really what you need instead: `DateRange[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, 3, 1}, "Month"]`. Also your expectation`1/{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31} // N` is wrong, you probably meant `1/Accumulate[{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}] // N` because you started with a fixed date `{2018, 12, 31}`

Comment: @flinty: Oh I see. OK thanks, I will use mixed radix units instead then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have noticed this problem too.  First, the OP's version.

```
Denominator@Rationalize@
    DateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, #, 1}, "Month"][[1]] & /@ Range@12
```

> {31, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30}

This was my solution.

```
dateDifference[from_, to_, u:"Month"] :=
 DateDifference[from + {0, 0, 1}, to + {0, 0, 1}, u]

Denominator@Rationalize@
    dateDifference[{2018, 12, 31}, {2019, #, 1}, "Month"][[1]] & /@ Range@12
```

> {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}

Comment: Quick and dirty but it works. Thanks!